# Searching through voice commands in Dragon NaturallySpeaking

Tags: windows-7, dragon-naturally-speaking

Is there any way to search through voice commands, without having to export the voice commands?

E.g. I would like to list all commands that contain "copy" in the command names. I am basically looking for some kind of  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>F</kbd> .

[image]

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently no possible to search through voice commands, without having to export the voice commands.